# How can I clean up my Mac to deleting entries I made using the defaults command line tool?

Tags: macos, command-line, defaults

I have accidentally added an entry to my defaults database (accessed via */usr/bin/defaults*) that is preventing me from installing apps via iTunes.

This is the command to read the offending entry:

```
/usr/bin/defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.usbmuxd
```

Which gives the following result:

```
{
    BlackList =     (
        "com.apple.iTunes"
    );
}
```

It was added by

```
/usr/bin/defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.usbmuxd BlackList -array-add com.apple.iTunes
```

I thought this would remove it, but I can't figure it out.

```
/usr/bin/defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.usbmuxd BlackList com.apple.iTunes
```

This just returns the help for defaults

Here are a few more things I've tried and the results

```
/usr/bin/defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.usbmuxd BlackList
Domain (/Library/Preferences/com.apple.usbmuxd) not found.

/usr/bin/defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.usbmuxd com.apple.iTunes
Domain (/Library/Preferences/com.apple.usbmuxd) not found.
```

Not sure what the "Domain not found" error is. I tried sudo as well and saw the same error message. Is that not the domain I just added to with the initial write step?

I think this is the command in defaults I want to use:

```
delete <domain> <key>                deletes key in domain
```

How do I undo / reverse  my change?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the BlackList array with

```bash
defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.usbmuxd BlackList
#        delete <domain>                               <key>
```

Apple doesn't provide an easy way to remove an array element. You can either set the BlackList array with `-array` with the item excluded, or edit the file manually using Xcode for example.

Comment: Looks right to me, the same thing I tried above, although I still get the same error of not finding the domain.

Comment: @Swim Domain not found means that file `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.usbmuxd.plist` can't be found. Does the file exist? Does using `defaults read` on that file still work? Did you do `defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.usbmuxd` without anything else on the end at some point?

Comment: Reading still works. I looked at the file in xcode like you suggested (good suggestion! I'm new to mac and didn't realize that was possible.) -- When trying to edit in xcode, I get a permission error. I did a sudo chmod 777, but it still had a permission error when trying to delete the entry in xcode.

Comment: Above, I should say instead of Reading works, say reading still returns the BlackList with com.apple.iTunes entry.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to print out the current array's value (which lists one value per line). Then you can use `grep -v '^    "my unwanted key" = '` to filter out the unwanted key, and set the array to that.

Example:

```shell
myplist=/Library/Preferences/com.apple.usbmuxd

/usr/bin/defaults write "$myplist" BlackList \
  "$(/usr/bin/defaults read "$myplist" BlackList \
    | grep -v '^    "com.apple.iTunes" = ')"
```